# Cell formatted as "Date" recognized in VBA as Vartype 8 - String

Tags: excel, vba

I stumbled upon something weird today.

I have a script, that check for vartype of a cell in order to convert it to a date. If it is not recognized ass Vartype 7, it gets parsed into date and replaces the original cell value.

However the script broke when other colleague tried to use it, so the problem is most probably somewhere in regional settings, but the weird part is that the cell is formatted as Date. As far as I can tell, it really is a date, excel formulas like DAY or MONTH work on it, as does Format or Month or Day in VBA. The issue however is that the Vartype is 8 - String.

Using CDate converts the format correctly as far as I can tell, not sure about dates that could have ambiguous day and month number.

What could be causing this? How can it be formatted and recognized as Date within excel, but VBA telling me it is a String?

Thank you

EDIT: Just checked, the format even within excel is not recognized as Date and ambiguous dates get their Date/Month swapped.

Comment: Would you be able to include some code that shows how you are reading/writing it?

Comment: Maybe that cell is a `TEXT` formula? Or maybe (it happens a lot of times) when pasting data to the sheet, dates are numbers stored as text, so Excel can't recognize it as Date.

Comment: What happens if you use IsDate to check if the value(s) are dates?

Comment: If VBA tells you it's a string, then it is a string - maybe that looks like a date. Formatting a cell doesn't tell anything about the content of a cell. Using a formula like Day on that cell will force Excel to convert the cell content for calculation if that's possible. `IsDate` is of no help as it will return true if conversion is possible. Same is true for VBA, it will to convert a string into a date.

Comment: *ambiguous dates get their Date/Month swapped*. That is your clue that the data has been entered incorrectly into Excel.  Most common reason is that the data source is a CSV file with DMY settings where the user's regional short date settings are MDY, or vice versa. Fix is to `IMPORT` the CSV file and, during that process, your user will have an opportunity to tell excel the format of the CSV file date column. Alternative is to change regional settings. Another alternative, if you have control, is to change the CSV date column to unambiguous (eg `yyyy-mm-dd`)